# PHP Scope and Class Instance Interaction

Tags: php, scope, visibility

It seems as though different instances of a class can know about each others' private member variables.

I have provided some code that attempts to showcase my issue, and I will try to explain it.

We have a class with a private member variable, `$hidden`. `modifyPrivateMember` sets the value of `$hidden` to `3`. `accessPrivateMember` takes an `Object` as a parameter and *accesses its **private** `$hidden` member* to return its value.

Example code:

```
<?php
// example.php

class Object {
    private $hidden;

    public function modifyPrivateMember() {
        $this->hidden = 3;
    }

    public function accessPrivateMember(Object $otherObject) {
        return $otherObject->hidden;
    }
}

$firstObject = new Object;
$firstObject->modifyPrivateMember();


$otherObject = new Object;
echo $otherObject->accessPrivateMember($firstObject);
```

Output of the above code:

```
$ php example.php
3
```

Can anyone explain why private members of objects are accessible to other instances of the same class? Is there some justification for this ostensible breach of scope?

Comment: The answers so far have just told me what the code has exemplified. I'm really looking for an answer to question of *why* things are this way. Why is visibility restricted to class and not object? What advantages does this offer?

Comment: I'm just speculating right now, but php borrows allot from java including modifier behavior. Maybe the java has to do it on class level because of the type system. Maybe that explains why ruby can do it on instance level. But again its just speculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`private` means it's restricted to only that class, not only that object.

Answer (score 3):

That's just how php works.  It's the same as how Java works.  See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php for more info.

Comment: The fact that Java works like this may actually be a valid answer why PHP works the same. But it's interesting to know the real answer that applies to all such languages.

Answer (score 1):

The only situation in which this behavior seemed useful was in a `factory` function:

```
class Object
{
    private $state;

    public static function makeObject()
    {
        $obj = new Object;
        $obj->state = 'some state';
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

Even in this case, there are better solution and I agree with you that it is a breach of scope, although not that big in my opinion. After all, the one who writes the class decides if she needs to access private members from objects passed as arguments. So, it may seem useless (even to me), but you never know. It's not like you're exposing your internals to subclasses or something. It all happens in the same class and it's your business what you're doing in there.

By the way, one language that implements access modifiers per object and not per class is Ruby.